# Pi zero iot hat 3G 4g modem

Tags: connection, hat, modem

Firstly I’ve looked everywhere and tried and tried to no avail.  I’ve set up the iot bit hat:

https://www.instructables.com/PiAnyWhere-4G-LTE-Hat-for-the-Raspberry-Pi/

To hopefully initiate the pi zero wh from an o2 simcard when there’s no Wi-Fi.

I have all the newest OS installed and it looks like it’s reading the sim etc.

However looking at iwconfig there is never any usb0 etc wireless connection.  Also shouldn’t I see an option to log into this Wi-Fi via the pi say on an iPad once connected?

If I run sudo a dial it seems to connect but then I can’t use the command screen unless I cnt and c to disconnect.

I get lines of stuff telling me about remote and local dns and then this:

--> secondary DNS address 82.132.254.3
--> pppd: ???[01]???[01]
--> pppd: ???[01]???[01]

Am I missing something obvious?

Any help gratefully received.

Rik

Comment: Check if the usb0 interface is being recognized by your Raspberry Pi. You can use the ifconfig command to see all network interfaces.
If usb0 is not showing up, Maybe there is an issue with the driver or configuration for the IoT Bit HAT.

Comment: did you install usb_modeswitch or some such?

Comment: Hi - no I didn’t. Should I? Just read somewhere it should go straight into pi USB and not a usb hat (which it is) so I’ll try that tomorrow when I get an adapter and get back.

Comment: Plugging straight into pi zero minus the hat has the same result…….

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks.  I get this when I run an `ifconfig` command:

```
usb0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 7e:fd:a6:6e:57:e4  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

When I run an `iwconfig` command; it says this for usb0:

```
usb0      no wireless extensions.
```

Any clues?

Thanks again.

Rik

Answer (score 0):

Update.  After messing with the wvdial.conf file I can now get modem initialising but I get repeatedly booted out via phone hang up and error 16?